# Change $scope variable value in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have three buttons here wish to make `$scope. -> q <-` `q` as variable. How can I achieve that. This is just a test code my actual problem is based on making `q` as variable so please do not suggest any workaround

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = function(q){
    $scope.a = "John Doe "; // $scope.q how to make q varibale
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <button ng-click="name('a')" ng-model="name">this is a</button>
<button ng-click="name('b')" ng-model="name">this is b</button>
<button ng-click="name('c')" ng-model="name">this is c</button>
{{a}} via a<br>
{{b}} via b<br>
{{c}} via c<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add q as a key to scope because $scope in nature is an object

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = function(q){
    $scope[q] = "John Doe "; // $scope.q how to make q varibale
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <button ng-click="name('a')" ng-model="name">this is a</button>
<button ng-click="name('b')" ng-model="name">this is b</button>
<button ng-click="name('c')" ng-model="name">this is c</button>
{{a}} via a<br>
{{b}} via b<br>
{{c}} via c<br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful however there is this problem that after $scope.b is set why the value in $scope.a still exist ? how can i bypass that

Comment: Thats the nature of js variables value assigned retains it till memory

Comment: The only way is to overwrite it

Comment: `$scope.name = function(q){
    var ar = ["a","b","c"]
    for(var i=0;i<=ar.length;i++)
    {
    $scope[ar[i]]=""
    }
    $scope[q] = "John Doe ";
    }`
Is this  the right way to do it?

Comment: yes sure its one of the way to do it if you have just 3 variables its feasible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134459/discussion-between-sam-and-vinod-louis).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = function(q){
    $scope[q] = "John Doe "+ q; // $scope.q how to make q varibale
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <button ng-click="name('a')" ng-model="name">this is a</button>
<button ng-click="name('b')" ng-model="name">this is b</button>
<button ng-click="name('c')" ng-model="name">this is c</button>
{{a}} via a<br>
{{b}} via b<br>
{{c}} via c<br>
</div>
```